# Import a dll file into another IDL file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, com

I am working on a project for developing a proxy COM component for the given component in visual C++.
If "Comp" is the original component and Proxy_Comp is the proxy component, then Proxy_Comp should be capable of having the same Interfaces as of the original component.

I think this should be done by importing only the "Comp.dll".
One of my friends has done this successfully before. But I cannot do it.  Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you are talking about the *importlib* directive in the IDL file.  It requires a type library, the filename extension is .tlb.  It is a binary file produced by running midl.exe on an .idl file that contains the .idl definitions in a compact form.

A DLL is not a type library.  It is a common convention however in COM Automation to embed the type library for the COM server as a resource inside the DLL.  Quite handy to keep the server code and its interface definitions together.  You can see this easily from Visual Studio, use File + Open + File and select the DLL.  You could pick c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll as an example.

The resource type name is invariably "TYPELIB", open the node to see the resource ID, invariably "1".  You can double click it to look at the content, not very interesting since it is only a hex dump.  You'll recognize the strings though, the names of the interfaces, coclasses and their members.

Close that window and right-click the "1", note the Export context menu option.  That lets you write a file to disk, name it something.tlb.  You'll now have an exact copy of the .tlb that the importlib() directive likes.

That .tlb can be decompiled in turn to re-generated the original .idl file.  Start the Visual Studio prompt.  Run oleview.exe, File + Open Typelib and select the .tlb.  Set the focus to the right pane, type Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C and paste that into a text editor.  Now you got the original .idl back, you could just use the *import* directive.

This only has 100% fidelity if the original .idl file was COM Automation clean and didn't contain any cpp_quote.

Comment: Your idea is really great and it works fine.  But my problem is different and I did not explain it clearly.  There is a client which invokes a method in the original component.  At runtime, the proxy should be created and it should provide the same Interface as the original component.  The Client should not feel that the proxy is different from the original component.

Comment: So far, I can inspect a original dll/tlb file and generate a proxy component at runtime.  I create new UUIDs for the interfaces in the proxy component.  But rather than creating new interface with new UUIDs, I should be able to make these interface point to the original component's interface.  Could you please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: library CalcProxyLib
{
 importlib("stdole2.tlb");
 importlib("C:\Users\Uma\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Tutorial\Calc\Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug\Calc.tlb");
 interface IDocHostUIHandlerDispatch;
 interface IAxWinAmbientDispatchEx;
[
uuid(2c43e5f4-b9e3-421f-8131-3d61ddc84446),
helpstring("Hello Class")
]
coclass Helloproxy
{
[default] interface IHello;
};
};

Comment: COM does not have a mechanism to substitute one interface implementation for another beyond the standard apartment interop proxies.  A client program call like CoCreateInstance() will always create an instance of the coclass as selected in the registry.  You can alter that registration but then you'll have to figure out a way to get the original implementation created so you can delegate the method calls from your proxy to the original.  No standard mechanism exists for that, it is entirely up to you to get that right.

Answer (score 2):

You want the interface definitions from the type library (.tlb data embedded in the DLL). If you have the Windows SDK utilities installed (probably with VS) then run [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688269.aspx) and "File", "View Typelib" for your DLL. That should give you an IDL dump that you can copy the interface definitions out of.

(There may also be a way to import the .tlb data at IDL compile time if that's what you're after, but I'm not sure sorry.)