# Implementing a COM interface in C++, methods not being exposed

Tags: c++, com

I'm writing a plugin implementing a 3rd-party interface in C++. I created an ATL project in MSVS, added an ATL Simple Object, then used the "Implement Interface" shortcut on that class. All of the interface methods got stubbed and it builds. I also added:

```
[assembly:System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComVisible(true)];
```

and have these running (successfully) after the build:

```
regsvr32.exe VWorksCPPATL.dll
regasm /codebase /tlb VWorksCPPATL.dll
```

However, when I open the DLL in oleview, I don't see any of the interface's methods exposed (aside from `IUnknown`) and the DLL doesn't get loaded by the container for the plugin.

When I open a working DLL that I wrote in C#, I see the interfaces that I've implemented and their methods listed under the coclass. (I had set the "register for COM interop" and "make assembly COM-visible" attributes on the project.)

When I open working DLLs that the vendor (creator of plugin container) wrote in C++, I see the exposed methods/interfaces in some, but not all, of the DLLs.

Do I need to manually modify my IDL file to expose these methods? Right now it shows (attributes omitted):

```
interface IPF400 : IDispatch{}
library VWorksCPPATLIB{
    coclass PF400{
        [default] interface IPF400;
    }
}
```

...Or am I likely having troubles for other reasons?

Comment: Do you see empty type library or no type library at all in COM/OLE Viewer? Do you see what you need in .TLB file produced among temporary build files?

Comment: The temporary TLB and the embedded TLB are the same. All they contain are the IDispatch members (GetTypeInfoCount, etc.). Pasted here: https://gist.github.com/zbjornson/8805c2e85b3d70dd2248dd387fbcf231. I assume I need to modify the IDL file to say I'm implementing the other interfaces, but I would hope there's an automatic way to do that.

Comment: Looks good. `IPF400` is there. Your IDL `IPF400` is also empty, just what you see in the compiled TLB.

Comment: @RomanR. do I need to manually add the methods of the interface that I've implemented to the IDL file then? I would have thought that the "implement interface" shortcut would do this for me, or that there's some other automatic way to generate it.

Comment: IDL's interface should not be empty. See [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782720/compile-dll-using-atl-with-method-parameter-as-interfaces-but-get-them-as-cocla) for sample IDL, see `IQTAction::Run` in particular. Not sure about automatic generation, but your IDL does have to have these definitions before you build the project.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Posted an answer with what I had to do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I had to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720309/import-a-dll-file-into-another-idl-file) to export the TLB from the DLL that contains the interface that I'm implementing, then add `importlib("....tlb")` and `interface IFooInterface` to the IDL file manually (attributes omitted):

```
interface IPF400 : IDispatch{
};

library VWorksCPPATLLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    importlib("IWorksDriver.tlb"); // <-- Added

    coclass PF400
    {
        interface IControllerClient; // <-- Added
        [default] interface IPF400;
    };

};
```